# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (50, 50, 1) but got array with shape (50, 50, 3)

Tags: python, keras

```
enter code here



      classifier = Sequential()


      classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=3, input_shape = (50, 50 , 1), activation =             
      'relu'))


      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


      classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation = 'relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

      classifier.add(Dropout(0.35))
      classifier.add(Flatten())


      classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.04))
      classifier.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))


      classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])



       from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

       train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

       validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

        training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/...',
                                             target_size = (50, 50),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')


         validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/…..',
                                        target_size = (50, 50),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'binary')


           history=classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     samples_per_epoch = 5187,
                     nb_epoch = 25,
                     validation_data = validation_set,
                     nb_val_samples = 1287)
```

This is the simple cnn architecture I have made. The image I have  used is grey scale .

If I specify channel value as 1 specified in bold
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=3, input_shape = (50, 50 , **1**), activation = 'relu'))

Im getting error as

Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (50, 50, 1) but got array with shape (50, 50, 3)

But if I use filter size as 3 I'm not getting any error but it might be a logical error of using 3 channel for grey scale images...Please clarify on this

Comment: Have you tried printing out the shape of your images when you load them, it's very probably what you say : your ray scale image could be loaded in memory with 3 channels. How did you read it ?

Comment: Thank you joseph...Just now I have checked ...It is taking its dimension as 3..Since Im a beginner is there any problem of taking it as 3 instead of ..1 If yes please provide some idea to convert it to grey scale...In which part I can modify the code?

Comment: You can either look into the `cv2.imread()` function of the `opencv` library, or more easily, take only the first chanel of your image into consideration : `img = img[:,:, 0]` (I would go for the 2nd option). Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`flow_from_directory` takes a `color_mode` parameter that specifies the number of channels the loaded images have. If you want to use grayscale images, you need to specify it (it defaults to `'rgb'`):

```
train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/...',
                                  color_mode='grayscale', #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                  target_size = (50, 50),
                                  batch_size = 32,
                                  class_mode = 'binary')
```

Comment: Thank you so much...No error after adding color-mode